# emacs-like "ignore case" in grep

Tags: grep, case-insensitive

Incremental search in `emacs` is case-insensitive by default if the search string is lowercase, and switches to case-sensitive as soon as there's a capital letter in the search string. Searching in `less` works the same way.

Is there an option to get an analogous behavior in `grep`? Or maybe in a grep-clone?

Comment: also: is stack-overflow the right place for this question, should this better go to another stack exchange site?

Comment: @NathanHughes: thanks I know, but in my workflow i'm using certain grep-aliases to where I would really like the described behavior.

Comment: https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep has `-S, --smart-case` which behaves like what you are describing

Comment: @sundeep: ripgrep works for me! if you add it as an answer i'll accept it (I wish it had `--include` and `--exclude` though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep has `-S, --smart-case` option which behaves like what you are describing.

It searches recursively by default, excludes files matched by `.gitignore` and other such files, ignores hidden files and directories and so on.

You can use `-g` option to include/exclude files matching a given glob pattern.

See my tutorial [ripgrep: Recursive options](https://learnbyexample.github.io/learn_gnugrep_ripgrep/ripgrep.html#recursive-options) for examples.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the `-g` option! but I can't see it on your tutorial page, it seems like that only covers gnu grep?

Comment: the book covers both GNU grep and ripgrep, but the link is specifically points to ripgrep recursive option section..

Comment: ahh now i see the section on the `-g` option. i must have missed it earlier ...

Answer (score 0):

In modern grep we can select from the following options:

1. Basic Regular Expressions (with or without case sensitivity)
2. Extended (Modern Awk-ish) Regular Expressions (with or without case sensitivity)
3. Perl-ish Regular Expressions (with or without case sensitivity)
4. Exact Match (with or without case sensitivity)
5. In all of the above, we can also invert the match

If we want more... AWK is probably our friend.